# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

Tags: java, jenkins

There is an APIGEE gateway to call endpoint, I'm loading the JKS file to Keystore while calling the service, I was succeeded in getting a response from my local. But when the same code runs from Jenkin's job giving me

```
 "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)" error with the same proxy and certificates used.
```

What could be the issue here? What change will fix the issue from Jenkin's job?

Appreciate your help!!

Have applied proxy and working in my local with out any issues.

The below code will help me return SSLConfig with JKS file loaded with it.

```java
public static SSLConfig getSSLConfig() throws IOException{

    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    SSLConfig config = null;

    File sslFile = new File("cx.p12");
    System.out.println("SSL_File:: "+sslFile.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(sslFile),
                    "test123".toCharArray());

            if (keyStore != null) {
                org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory clientAuthFactory = new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(keyStore, "test123");
                config = new SSLConfig().with().sslSocketFactory(clientAuthFactory).and().allowAllHostnames();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error while loading keystore >>>>>>>>>");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      return config;
}
```

---

//And, would be calling the service with required `proxy` and `SSLConfig`. Which gives me success in local.

```java
EncoderConfig encoderconfig = new EncoderConfig();
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().sslConfig(SSLHandshakeUtility.getSSLConfig());
Response response = RestAssured.given().
                    log()
                    .all()
                    .config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderconfig.appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
                    .proxy(proxy,port)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("apiKey",apikey)
                    .header("ENV","DEV")
                    .body(payload)
                    .post(url);
```

**Expected:** Response from the service similar to local run in Jenkin's job.

**Actual:** `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)` from Jenkin's job.

Comment: Issue is with the system proxy being passed to the call and I fixed by passing the correct proxy and port.